# Conditions for existence and uniqueness of a matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Let $A$ and $B$ be given $(n\times m)$-matrices ($n\geq 2$, $m\geq 2$), and let $X$ be an unknown $(n\times n)$-matrix such that $$XA=B.$$ When does such a solution $X$ of this matrix equation exist? When does $X$ exist and is unique?

As I see, one has $$A^T X^T=B^T.$$ So, the necessary and sufficient condition for existence of $X$ is $$\mathrm{rank}(A^T)=\mathrm{rank}(A^T|B^T)$$ or (that is the same) $$\mathrm{rank}(A)=\mathrm{rank} \Bigg(\frac{\boxed{A}}{\boxed{B}}\Bigg).$$ Is it possible to simplify this condition or write simpler conditions?

Comment: Be careful, $A^{-1}$ has no sense since $A$ is not a square matrix.

Comment: Yes, I missed it. Thank you very much. I've already fixed it.

Comment: If you have full rank, you will always be able to find a solution of either $XA =B$ or $AX=B$ via the [pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse)